# Error of The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (AlarmReceiver, int)

Tags: java, android

I need solution for this:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Time is up!!!!.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Vibrate the mobile phone
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(2000);
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.abc1);
    mp.start();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BroadcastReceiver` is not sub class of `Context`..so Change this

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.abc1);
```

into

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.abc1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the 'onReceive' method `this` refers to the AlarmReceiver, not the activity context. So change to:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.abc1);
```